# Обработка массива произвольно длины AVR

Tags: ассемблер

Есть пример, приведу чуть ниже. В общем разбирался, разбирался с памятью, в целом всё понятно, но непонятно как сделать задание - чтобы программа обрабатывала массив произвольно длины. Есть такой код:

```
.DSEG
.ORG 0x60
arr: .BYTE 10

.CSEG ;сегмент кода

rjmp Reset ;вектор прерывания, вызываемого по сбросу микроконтроллера

Reset: ;начало программы
ldi XH,HIGH(arr) ;указатель X проинициализирован значением
ldi XL,LOW(arr) ;адреса начала массива arr
ldi YH,HIGH(arr+10) ;указатель Y проинициализирован значением
ldi YL,LOW(arr+10) ;адреса следующего за последним элементом массива arr
ldi r16,5 ;загрузка в счетчик цикла r16 числа 5

cycle:
ld r0,X ;копирование в r0 содержимого ячейки ОЗУ, на которую указывает X
ld r1,-Y ;копирование в r1 содержимого ячейки ОЗУ, на которую
         ;указывает Y с предварительным уменьшением Y на единицу
st Y,r0 ;копирование r0 в ячейку ОЗУ, на которую указывает Y
st X+,r1 ;копирование r1 в ячейку ОЗУ, на которую указывает X 
         ;с последующим увеличением X на единицу
dec r16 ;r16<-(r16-1)
cpi r16,0x00 ;сравнение r16 с нулем
brne cycle ;повторение цикла, если не 0
rjmp PC ;бесконечный цикл
```

Как я понял, исходя из условия, мне нужно сделать так, что я могу поставить *любое* число в arr: .BYTE ****
и оно нормально обработалось.
Значит каким-то макаром надо, чтобы Y знал конец, ну и потом со счетчиком уже проще будет
вот как сделать так, чтобы Y знал конец массива?
Или вообще не в ту сторону копаю и не правильно думаю?

Comment: А если просто поставить метку после `arr: .BYTE 10` и инициализировать YH/YL адресом этой метки?

Comment: А если будет не 10, а 100, например? как Y понять, что конец уже не 10? Или я не так понимаю?

Comment: Ну

    .DSEG
    .ORG 0x60
    arr: .BYTE 100
    arrend:
    ...
    ldi YH,HIGH(arrend) ;указатель Y проинициализирован значением
    ldi YL,LOW(arrend) ;адреса следующего за последним элементом массива arr

А уж адреса сосчитает ассемблер

Comment: Спасибо! А по счетчику не подскажете? Пока не знаю, как "поймать" число (собственно, из .byte), которое нужно в том числе счетчиком сделать.

Comment: Счётчик (боюсь наврать). Надеюсь такие выражения в этом ассемблере допустимы.

    ldi r16,(arrend-arr)/2

А вообще, если это не учебная задача, то лучше писать на C (хотя бы порт gcc для avr8. Для виндов оно называется winavr)

Comment: такого деления нет конечно, но сдвигом влево, в общем-то решается, так что попробую, спасибо.

Comment: да, задачка учебная)

Comment: Нет у меня под рукой avrstudio, да и виндов тоже, но вот почему "деления конечно нет" -- непонятно. Это же константные выражения, так что может и быть. А сдвиг если есть, то со времён языка Си у него может быть странный приоритет. Так что смотрите на сгенерированный код (или в отладчике)

Comment: если надо поделить на 2, то сдвигом вправо решается

Comment: Ну, говоря о делении и сдвиге вы разные вещи имеете в виду. @alexlz говорит о *программе* ассемблер, а автор и @2Roman явно имеют в виду машинные команды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы программа могла обработать массив произвольной длины, то в любом случае необходима информация о длине массива. Она должна быть либо в виде отдельного числа, в котором хранится длина массива, либо в самом массиве должен быть признак его конца. Например, признаком конца кодируются строки ASCIIZ - эти строки представляют из себя обычные массивы произвольной длины, у которых в конце массива обязательно есть нулевой элемент.

Comment: (Лимит к комментариев к вопросу исчерпан, поэтому здесь) Посмотрел pdf'ку -- help по avr assembler'у. Там есть в выражениях и деления и сдвиги.

http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404-2010/docs/Atmel-AVR-Assembler-Help.pdf